# Как сделать так, чтобы когда объект находится в нужной позиции, произошло действие?

Tags: if, lua

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда оба объекта были в нужном месте, произошло какое то действие, а пока они не находятся в нужном месте - ничего не должно происходить.
Например:

```
if ( 
setPosition("bl2", 437, 166) && 
setPosition("bl1", 407, 166))
getObject("f1").ghost = true;
```

Я новичок и не совсем понимаю, как сделать правильно. Может быть что то в скрипте не правильно, буду рад если поможете. Спасибо за понимание!

Игра: Трагедия белок.

Comment: вам нужно понять принцип как это должно работать или реализовать это для конкретного рабочего фрэймворка? Если второе, то явно не хватает инфы о используемом фрэймворке

Answer (score 0):

Конкретного ответа без предоставления информации о конкретном API вам никто не даст. Если вас устроит теоретический абстрактный ответ, то здесь не достаточно одних лишь сеттеров и геттеров. Вам нужно сверять координаты через event loop. Если тот код, который вы показали в примере, уже находится внутри цикла событий, то здесь просто нужно заменить сеттеры геттерами. Как-то так:

```lua
if getPosition("bl1") == {437, 166} && getPosition("bl2") == {407, 166} then
    print("какое-то событие")
end
```

Естественно, код в моём ответе не имеет ничего общего с реальным кодом. Это лишь пример.

Comment: стоит также упомянуть о `collision detection` - вряд ли размеры объекта всего 1x1 едениц (если только, конечно, речь не идет о тайловом мире)